# can't set width for auxheader in zk

Tags: zk, zk-grid

I have a grid in which I want to set the width for auxheader in .zul but it's not working. I am using zk framework.

```
<grid id="chartGrid" model="@bind(vm.chartGridModel)" mold="paging" 
      style="overflow:auto" width="100%"  >
    <auxhead hflex="2" >
        <auxheader hflex="2" align="center" width="200px" label="Date" rowspan="3"/>
    </auxhead>
    <auxhead hflex="1"  children="@bind(vm.legendsFB)" visible="@bind(vm.vFb)" >
        <auxheader align="center" width="200px" colspan="1"></auxheader>
          <template name="children">
                <auxheader align="center" label="@bind(each)" colspan="@bind(
                     vm.viewType eq '0' ? 3 :2)" hflex="2"/>
            </template>
    </auxhead>

    <columns visible="false"><!-- make it invisible -->
    <column width="200px"/><!-- specify width here -->
    <column width="150px"/>
    <column width="50px"/>
    <column width="50px"/>
    </columns>
<template name="model">
    <row>
          <cell align="center" ><label  value="@load(each.report_date)"></label>
          </cell>
          <cell align="center"><label value="@load(each.total_action)"></label>
          </cell>    
          <cell align="center"><label value="@load(each.from_user_male)"></label>
          </cell>    
          <cell align="center"><label value="@load(each.from_user_female)"></label>
          </cell>    
    </row>
</template>
</grid>
```

Comment: Are you getting a specific error? If not, then what happens? You can edit your question to include more information.

Comment: i got a header but it have width not work (it was default). I want to set the width for each column is my mind

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You set width and colspan.

colspan="x" means you will take the witdh of x columns of your template.

Now you can **remove the colspan** and it should work, but remember when you set width in px,
Be sure that the total px are the same as the px of all your rows.

You can also do width = "20%", this would mean that you take 20% of your total size of px of the columns.
Its easier to calculate to 100% then your total px.

Greetz chill.